# Can we deploy a core PHP project in a folder of a node project on AWS

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, hosting

I have a node project hosted on an AWS server.  Now I want to deploy a PHP project in a of that project. Is it possible to do so?

Example:
My node project is on the domain - dummydomain.com
I want to host a PHP project on - dummydomain.com/folderforphpproject

Comment: *That* is possible, however the *how* depends on the way the node.js project is currently setup and how the domain routing is configured, etc.